# Missing newline character in rawlogs using log4j and slf4j

Tags: maven, logging, log4j2, slf4j

I am working on a bug using log4j2 and slf4j. I have been reviewing the commit history in Github, but cannot find where the bug was introduced. In the log file `rawlogs.log` the newline character `%n` has been replaced by `%replace%n`. Please see the example below:

`applog.line=16,applog.msg=ConfigChangeListener Initilized!%replace%nXXXXXXXX03172     123456789   2019-06-11 15:06:35.080 devHostname`

I am using the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.10.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

In the files with logs the `LoggerFactory` is created with the example below:

`private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClassName.class);`

I have tried using both a `log4j2.properties`, and `log4j2.xml` files from log4j2 examples, but always get this error on startup:

`2019-06-11 15:19:16,063 warmup - 7 ERROR No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.`

The `rawlogs.log` file is created and populated on startup.

Has anyone experienced this before? Any insight is appreciated.

EDIT:  To clarify, project did not use a .xml or .properties file for configurations. I introduced them in an attempt to expose the root cause of the bug, but have not had success.

Comment: Seems you are using a custom and private implementation: com.walmart.platform.logging.

Comment: I edited to include the current dependencies. Thanks for catching that. Bad copy/paste on my part.

Comment: Seems the `%replace` pattern layout is incomplete. Should be `replace{pattern}{regex}{substitution}`  https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html

Comment: Thank you for the comment. This morning I am trying to see where the ``%replace`` pattern is declared. I do not see it anywhere in the project.

Comment: If you are not providing a logback.xml or similar, then it's using the default inside the dependency jar.